# Lisp board count pieces

Tags: function, lisp, common-lisp

I need to make a function in lisp that counts the pieces in my board. Let me explain my issue/game:

i have a board (10x10) like so:

```
(
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
)
```

in this board we will represent two types of pieces:

- 1 by 1 squares
- 2 by 2 squares

they will be positioned in my board like so:

```
(
    (0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0)
    (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
    (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
    (0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0)
    (0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0)
    (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0)
    (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
    (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
    (0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0)
    (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
    )
```

In this example I have four 1-by-1 squares and two 2-by-2 squares.
I need a function that counts how many of a given type of piece I have in my board.

Example:

```
(defun countPiece (board pieceType)
   ; here I am supposed to write my code
)
```

so if I called `(countPiece (testBoard) 'twoByTwoSquare)` it returns `2`, for example where testboard is a function that returns a sample board with a few pieces positioned

However, I dont know where to begin. any tips?

EDIT: There can never be pieces together horizontally nor vertically. Only in diagonal

Comment: I would begin with learning some Lisp basics first, before beginning to program. Here is a great introductory Lisp book, for download: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Comment: Your representation seems to make this impossible: you can't distinguish between a single 2x2 tile and four suitably-placed 1x1 tiles.

Comment: yeah i forgot to mention something, i will edit my post thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not fluent in lisp, so my answer will only give you the algorithmic solution:

```
singlePieces = empty list
doublePieces = empty list

for each row
    for each column
        if ((value[row][column] = 1)
           and ((row - 1, column - 1) not in doublePieces)
           and ((row - 1, column) not in doublePieces)
           and ((row, column - 1) not in doublePieces)) then
            if ((row < rowCount)
               and (column < columnCount) and (value[row][column + 1] = 1)
               and (value[row + 1][column] = 1)
               and (value[row + 1][column + 1]) = 1) then
                doublePieces.add(row, column)
            else
                singlePieces.add(row, column)
            end if
        end if
    end for
end for
```

Comment: The algorithm should explain the solution. If the downvote is correct here and algorithms are unwelcome here instead of lisp code, then please, let me know, so I will remove the answer.

Comment: Any attempt to help is welcome. i didn't downvote. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Neymarjr I know you didn't, you do not have enough reputation to do so, but of course, the person who downvoted may be right or wrong in downvoting. If that is a correct action here, then I should remove my answer, so, please copy this answer to a text editor so it will help you even if I remove it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how to do it with lists:

```
(defun count-pieces (board &aux (small 0) (big 0))
  (loop for (row next) on (cons nil board)
    for bigs = nil then
    (loop for (tl tr) on row
      for (bl br) on (or next (mapcar (constantly 0) row)
      for n from 0
      for nearly-bigp = (every #’plusp (list tl tr bl br))
      for bigp = nearly-bigp then (and nearly-bigp (not pbigp))
      and pbigp = nil then bigp
      for ninbig = (or (member n bigs) (and bigp (member (1+ n) bigs)))
      if (and ninbig bigp)
        collect n and collect (+ n 1)
        and do (incf big)
      else if ninbig do (incf small)))
  (values big small))
```

I wrote this on my phone so I’m not sure it works. It’s also a little clumsy. It’s also probably worth using arrays instead of lists and it might be worthwhile to e.g. represent a big piece with -1 or 2 or 3 so that they may be easily distinguished.